# Checking if my username X is the same guy as username Y

Tags: identity-theft, identification

I'm creating a new alias online for creative works that I don't want anyone I know in real life to see, but I'd like it to be possible for online people to check that things copyrighted and licensed to my old alias (username X) are also copyrighted and licensed to my new alias (username Y), but without me having to reveal my username X identity via username Y identity or vice versa. If someone sees that something I (under username Y) use is owned by username X, I need to tell the person that I'm not a thief/infringer because I'm the same guy, but I can't say that I'm the same guy because it's very googlable and it can spread viral online.

I was thinking if it would be secure to say on my username X account "If you think someone stole my works, use a CRC32 check on this username and the suspect's username and if the code is *insert code here*, that means that I am that person."

Is this secure? Could it be possible that an imposter abuses the code and creates an alias that just fits the code in order to steal my identity? What algorithm should I use that is safe enough to do this?

Comment: Low tech solution: When you as Y post works attributed to X, include a text like "Used with permission from X."

Comment: Isn't this just security by obscurity? Once someone does the check and discovers that the aliases are the same person, what's to stop them from announcing that fact publicly?

Comment: Anyone can search if the same work exists (like search by image). On those results, X and Y will be listed. If both users attribute ownership of that work, people will start asking you if X=Y. If you don't answer openly, people won't know who is the real owner, and thus, both accounts will be affected (I would be suspicious of any of the two). If you do answer, then everything is revealed. If you publish the same work under the 2 names, its matter of time before people will know it. The best approach I think is the one proposed by Robert & Anders.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a licensing/permission question. It can only be addressed by adding the information "Used with permission from X" to anything posted from User Y that is using something created by User X. At this point both accounts are completely separated and you are using User X content with permission. Now User X has their License(s), and User Y has their License(s), and User Y can use it with permission(if you didn't grant yourself permission I'd be VERY surprised).

The only place this could be an issue is when User X licenses everything but their own usage to a third party. At that point you actually have to ask permission from that third party, otherwise you're violating your own licensing agreement as far as they know!

At that point however they will know, and there is no way to prevent that should that scenario come up.

---

## Something to be careful of!

This is really just **Security Through Obscurity** and isn't really security. It only delays someone in finding out who you are. When they have discovered that, then this means nothing if they tell someone. Really what you're doing is impersonating someone who does not exist, and pretending you aren't you. Unless you go the REAL extra mile and take legal steps to change this, you're still you.

Comment: If someone searches online for my real name, no works of my new alias should appear. But if someone wants to know if my new alias is the guy with my real name which is me, I want to tell them. Basically, nobody in real life should know the works of the new alias.

Comment: Then obfuscation is really what you're doing(this answer). That's fine and dandy, but remember it's not real security. It's just a mask. Once that mask is cracked people can find out.

Comment: I actually do take that risk, but nobody would do that to the extent that my new alias's works show up while searching for my real name.

Comment: @drewbenn flagged as non constructive. Just because my work looks like someone else means nothing unless you can prove anything. correlation does not equal causation

Comment: Again, correlation does not equal causation. What the OP wants is that if people search his REAL name, User Y won't show up.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're saying at this point based on what I've read from the user one the first few comments they made on this answer.

Comment: The only way I'd share content between X and Y is by using this algorithm which lets people check if X+Y equals a hash that I provide. The MD5 is bad because it can reverse the code back to X+Y, but what I want is that once the user does X+Y hash, the algorithm checks if that equals to the hash that I make. If someone does X+Z where Z is some random guy who's not me, the algorithm should output a different hash than the one that I provide.